# Relative Layouts change when showing save data

Tags: android-layout

hy I am using relative layouts for input data into SQLiteDatabase and showing it .
 it work ok when i am taking input but it changes its position on displaying ?

Comment: please post your code

Comment: Relative layout
width match parent & height 150

Comment: Fabio sir should i change it into Linear Layout

Comment: dont have clarity in this.please post your code

Comment: Need more clarity of ypur post. Screenshots and code highly appreciate